# \itemize dash appears in gray in PDF

Tags: itemize

I'm writing my report with Latex and I have some itemize environnement.

In PDF, the dashes are gray and not black as the text is.

Could you help me ? Thank you.

EDIT : Also the cadratin dashes (--) are grey

Comment: But there is not the problem in the pdf reader built in TexMaker.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `itemize` labels are hierarchically defined as

```
\newcommand\labelitemi{\textbullet}
\newcommand\labelitemii{\normalfont\bfseries \textendash}
\newcommand\labelitemiii{\textasteriskcentered}
\newcommand\labelitemiv{\textperiodcentered}
```

where each of the `\text...` commands are taken from a font. Most notably, `\textendash`, obtained via `--` is different from setting two separate dashes `-` and `-`. The thinner replacement of `--` sometimes appear lighter in colour (or grey under black font colour).

Suggestions for overruling your `itemize` woes would be to use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and specify the label that suits you using the `label=...` key-value:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}

% Regular/default settings
\begin{itemize}
  \item Level 1
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Level 2
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Level 3
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Level 4
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

% Updated settings at each level (supplied via optional argument from enumitem)
\begin{itemize}
  \item Level 1
  \begin{itemize}[label={\rule[.5ex]{1.5ex}{1pt}}]
    \item Level 2
    \begin{itemize}[label=$\star$]
      \item Level 3
      \begin{itemize}[label=+]
        \item Level 4
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Above I've updated the display for the second and subsequent levels in `itemize` to be different:

- Level 2 displays a thicker rule (via `\rule`);
- Level 3 displays a star (via `$\star$`);
- Level 4 displays a plus `+`.

Alternatively (if you don't want to use `enumitem`), update the respective macros given at the top of the post. You can also make similar global definitions using `enumitem` (see the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf)).